# How to display data from xml as Gridview linq to xml c#

Tags: c#, gridview, linq-to-xml

Instead of writing this code to the console I want to display as Gridview in order to export to a excel spreadsheet. What settings and setup do I have make in VStudio and the code. I am fairly new to c# programming please help.

```
 class Program
{
    public class XAxisCalib
    {

        public int Max1 { get; set; }
        public int Min2 { get; set; }
        public int Max3 { get; set; }
        public int Min4 { get; set; }
        public int Max5 { get; set; }
        public int Min6 { get; set; }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {


            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                            select new
                            {

                                MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                                MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                            };

                foreach (var x in query)
                {
                    foreach (var nextLevel in x.MaxChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                    }
                    foreach (var nextLevel in x.MinChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                    }

                }



                var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                             select new
                             {

                                 MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                                 MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                             };


                foreach (var y in query2)
                {
                    foreach (var nextLevel in y.MaxChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                    }
                    foreach (var nextLevel in y.MinChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                    }

                    var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                                 select new
                                 {

                                     MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                                     MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                                 };

                    foreach (var z in query3)
                    {
                        foreach (var nextLevel in z.MaxChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                        }
                        foreach (var nextLevel in z.MinChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                        }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way is to load the XML into a DataSet and use it as DataSource for your GridView.

for more info have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx